# See contents of SD card in terminal window on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, command-line, terminal, sd-card

I have photos on my SD Card. I can not see the files on my Mac. I can see it in my camera and when I load the micro SD card in phone, I can see the pics. My Mac is not showing any files. I am assuming there could be some kind of virus that had made the files hidden.

I want to see these files in Terminal (just like I would do in DOS).

Comment: `cd` to the card and then `ls -al`? (I don't know if OSX has 'hidden' files - on Linux and BSD, a file is hidden if the filename starts with a '.' character.)

Comment: my card name is "phone card" but cd "phone card" does not work

Comment: You have to be in the directory where the OS mounts it - in OS X it's probably `/Volumes`, so you would need to `cd "/Volumes/phone card"` (or `cd /Volumes/phone\ card`).

Comment: @user55325, that works, you can post it as answer. And extra help would be, how do I copy files from my SD card to my mac drive, lesser say documents folder. Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

To list the contents of the card, first `cd /Volumes/<card name>` - in this case `cd /Volumes/phone\ card` (the `\` escapes the space). Then you can do `ls -al` to list the files (hidden and visible) on the card.

If you want to copy files to somewhere else on the drive, you can use `cp`. For example, to copy files to your home directory, `cp <some file> ~` (or to copy everything, `cp -R ./* ~`, where * means "match any character(s)" and ~ is short for your home directory (I don't remember the OS X default directory hierarchy). `-R` means copy directories recursively (if cp encounters a directory, it should copy the contents of the directory as well).

`man cp` will tell you more about cp (or any other command).